# How to use Pocketsphinx with c#?

Tags: c#, pocketsphinx

Good day!
I try to use pocketsphinx with c# ,but do not know how to do that.
Can you give me some links on examples, or piece of code?

Thank you!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900923/calling-pocketsphinx-in-c-sharp-accesviolationexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) to generate a C# wrapper for PocketSphinx lib, like it done here:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-unity-demo/tree/master/Assets/Pocketsphinx

There is a piece of code that uses generated wrapper:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-unity-demo/blob/master/Assets/TestScript.cs

Answer (score 3):

I created an example, ready to use, Windows Phone example. 
[github](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-wp-demo)

probably also usable for Windows 10 / UWP, otherwise I will make it compatible soon myself in the example.